# python telegram bot issue: accessing json data

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot

im building a script in python for a chat group. i am trying to add a / command for the user to get info from a json output. i can have them see the full json output like

```
def eosvol(bot, update):
    """Send a message when the command /vol is issued."""

    volCallJson = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/generateAvg?fsym=EOS&tsym=USD&e=Kraken").json()
    vol_name = (volCallJson)
    volOut = volCallJson  
    update.message.reply_text(volOut)
```

and this is what sends it to user

```
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("eosvol", eosvol))
```

i would like to select parts of the json data but i get errors like

```
vol_name = volCallJson()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

or

```
line 341, in loads
raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

i understand im not accessing the json correctly. im just not sure how to do so.

Comment: could you print this line output and see `volCallJson = requests.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/generateAvg?fsym=EOS&tsym=USD&e=Kraken")`

Comment: yes, my users end gets the raw json format. I am having difficulty selecting from the data and only outputing what i need.

Comment: can you give the _pprint_  output of the raw json and tell what exactly you need as output ?

Comment: i solved it, thanks :D